# How to add text to JTextArea? java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have three buttons in in my program and a JTextArea. What I want to do is, when the user presses a button/s I want the JTextArea to have the text saying button 1 was pressed, button 2 was pressed and so on. for example.

```
JButton button1 = new JButton();
JButton button2 = new JButton();
JButton button3 = new JButton();

JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(button1);
frame.add(button2);
frame.add(button3);
frame.add(text);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

What I want to do is, when the user presses button 1, I want the JTextArea to have the text saying Button 1 was press and then if the user presses button 2, I want the JTextArea to have the previous text and the text for button 2. so it should say something like;

```
button 1 was pressed
button 2 was pressed
```

edit:

so have the text like so,

```
button 1 was pressed button 2 was pressed
button 3 was pressed
```

and if I had more buttons, it will look like this

```
button 1 was pressed button 2 was pressed
button 3 was pressed button 4 was pressed
button 5 was pressed button 6 was pressed
```

and so on.

Comment: Have you looked @ the docs?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html - it extends JTextComponent (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html) which has a `setText` method.

Comment: Make your text variable an instance field, not a local field, and then use it in your ActionListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `actionListener` to each botton which will invoke

```
yourTextArea.append("button X was pressed\n");
```

Here is simple demo

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

final JTextArea area = new JTextArea(2,20);
frame.getContentPane().add(area);

JButton button1 = new JButton("press me");
JButton button2 = new JButton("press me");

button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        area.append("button 1 was pressed\n");
    }
});
button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        area.append("button 2 was pressed\n");
    }
});

frame.getContentPane().add(button1);
frame.getContentPane().add(button2);

frame.setSize(300,300);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

---

You can also use

```
try {
    area.getDocument().insertString(0,"button 1 was pressed\n", null);
} catch (BadLocationException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

instead of

```
yourTextArea.append("button X was pressed\n");
```

if you want to add new lines at start of text area.

Comment: hi what does new JTextArea(2,20); the 2, 20 mean?

Comment: @user3288493 It is default number of rows and columns. Have a look at [documentation of this constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#JTextArea%28int,%20int%29).

Comment: is there any append function for JTextPane?

Comment: @user3288493 I am not sure, but you can try using Document as text representation of text content (use `yourTextPane.getDocument()`). With this you can try inserting new strings like I did in my answer, but if you want to place at the end of text try instead of `0` using number of characters document contains. You should be able to do it via `document.getLength()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add action listeners to your buttons something like this:

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        textArea.append("button 1 was pressed");

    }
});
```

Dont forget to declare textArea at class level.

Hope this helps

Comment: Sanjeev, hi thanks, append was what I need to add. one question though, how can you bring the text to next line?

Comment: `textArea.append("\n");`

Comment: @user3288493 textArea.append("button 1 was pressed\n");

Comment: Also, would it be possible to have for example, text in a 2 by 2 grid e.g. text here text here then more text under that.

Comment: yeah thats possible, it will take little more effort to do that. I think you should try it yourself first. it will be fun for you.

Comment: @Sanjeev, is there any append function for JTextPane?

Answer (score 1):

Before you add the button to the frame do this:

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Here write what you want to be execute when button is pressed
        }
    });
```

For better details about this visit : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html